# How to Stop Strike-Through Text On Hyphen?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I've noticed that LibreOffice writer will auto strike-through any text that ends in a hyphen.

I'm taking notes on philosophy texts that have many German words that have hyphens in them, and it always keeps strikeing-through it.

Is there any way to disable this shortcut?

Essentially, this is what happens:
I want to type "ways-of-being", and I type ways, then a hyphen ->

[image: Ways]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why no one got back to you after all this time, but since I found the answer I believed you were WAY overdue one.  Below is a link where the answer is just above what looks like screen shots, along with answers to other auto-format occurrences.  Hope this helps you as much as it did me!

https://askubuntu.com/questions/897464/in-libreoffice-what-is-the-shortcut-for-italics

Summary from the linked answer: Go to Tools > AutoCorrect > AutoCorrect Options and select "Options" tab. Uncheck the checkboxes for `Automatic *bold*, /italic/, -strikeout- and _underline_`.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.